# WPF application does not run when installed after publishing

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I successfully publish (at least Visual Studio says so) a WPF application to the FTP server of my website. After the publish, VS redirects me to the page where the download is available.

I click on download, setup file gets downloaded and Windows asks me about if I want to install this app with unknown publisher. I say yes and files were downloaded.

But after this procedure, I don't see any folder or file in `program files`. Only a `shortcut` of the application created in start menu. that's it.

Is this a common problem or should I provide some more details?

Comment: ClickOnce apps are installed in the User's local folders, something like `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Apps\`. As for why it doesn't run, you're going to have to provide more detail.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ well. Inside apps folder I see some files and folders but it doesn't look good. I could only find my application's icon and manifest file. No exe file. I don't know how I can describe it.